# Run excel macro from DXL export

Tags: excel, vba, ibm-doors

I've found a piece of code to export a DOORS view to excel (using the built in function). However, it doesn't give acces to the OleObject from which I would be able to run a vba macro.

So my question is : How can I make a export to Excel and then run a macro in one click? 
I took a look to the excel.dxl built-in function used to do the export but I'm not very good when it comes to DXL ann OleObject...

Thanks in advance,

PS : here is the code used to export from a given view

```
    //post by Jim(iron-man?) https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014305335#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014587301

Skip selectedItems = getSelectedItems ()
Item I = null

for I in selectedItems do
{
    if(isDeleted(I) || null I) {continue}
        if (type (I) == "Formal")
        {
                Module m = read(fullName(I),true)
                load view "ExcelExport"
                //delete column 0//dont know why this was here to delete the first column after loading the view.
                {
                        // override some default message box functions, so they will only print the data but 
                        // not pause execution. Write to a log file here! 

                        bool confirm (string s) { print "Confirmed: " s "\n"; return true }
                        void ack (string s) {print "Acknowledge: " s "\n" }
                        void acknowledge (string s) {print "Acknowledge: " s "\n"  }
                        void infobox (string s) {print "Info: " s "\n" }
                        void info (string s) {print "Info: " s "\n" }

                        DB theDiag = null

                        // Now override block and show, to only do realize
                        void show  (DB x) { realize x; theDiag = x }
                        void block (DB x) { realize x; theDiag = x }

                        if (null current Module) {
                                print "You need to have a current Module set for the export."
                                halt
                        }

                        // we need braces, since -D will be executed at top level and we will get name
                        // clashes for variable defined in word.dxl and the other includes of it.
                        {
                                // now include the word.dxl -> this will pop up the dialog, but not halt execution
                                // due to the overrides above
                                #include <standard/export/office/excel.dxl> //for the standard excel exporter

                                // here we can change the dialog options. See itfui2.inc and word.dxl for all 
                                // the options
                               // set(exportHeadingsToggle, false)   // turn off export of headings
                               //set(exportWarnUnregOLE,false)   //turn off ole warning

                                // now manually launch the export button callback
                                doExcel theDiag //for the standard excel exporter

                                // get rid of the dialog
                                if (!null theDiag) destroy theDiag
                                                                // close DOORS
                                //exit_
                        }
                }
                close(m)

        }
}

delete selectedItems
```

Comment: Hey- just wondering, is there something you NEED from the built in exporter? Or are you just leveraging it because it is there? This will help inform my answer.

Comment: hi,

I'm using the build in exporter cause it looks pretty easy to use (just `doExcel` and there it is).

As I say, I look into it to find how excel is called and so on but i cannot figure it out